# Can't create object: ADODB.Stream

Tags: vb6, vbscript

I am trying to create ADODB.Stream object in VBscript. This is the function:

```
   Function ByteArray2Text(varByteArray)
'Convert byte array into a string with ADODB.Stream
'Data should be real plain text because binary data will be mangled
Dim byt
Const adTypeText = 2
Const adTypeBinary = 1
    Set byt = CreateObject("ADODB.Stream")
    byt.Type = adTypeBinary
    byt.Open
    byt.Write varByteArray
    byt.Position = 0
    byt.Type = adTypeText
    byt.CharSet = "us-ascii"
    ByteArray2Text = byt.ReadText
    byt.Close
    Set byt = Nothing
End Function
```

When I try to run this function i am getting error:

```
Microsoft VBScript runtime error: ActiveX component can't create object: 'ADODB.Stream'
```

What i need to do, to create this ADODB.Stream object?

Comment: May be of interest: Disable stream object http://support.microsoft.com/kb/870669

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that:

1. The Stream component exits on your computer.
2. If it exists, type this at run dialog:

```
regsvr32 "path\stream_file_here.dll"
```

Chances are that the steam component file has been unregistered in the registry and you can't create an object of that.

Comment: Where can i found "stream_file_here.dll"?

Comment: well, you will have to see the documentation for that or do a bit of googling about that. thanks

Comment: The stream_file_here.dll part is very funny :-))

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that you have [MDAC](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/aa937730.aspx) installed.

Answer (score 0):

You also can try Microsoft Jet 4.0

You can also register these DLLs:

```
REGSVR32 "(path to "common files")\System\ole db\sqloledb.dll"
REGSVR32 "(path to "common files")\System\ole db\Oledb32.dll"
REGSVR32 "(path to "common files")\System\ole db\Msdasql.dll"
REGSVR32 "(path to "common files")\System\msadc\Msadce.dll"
```

They have relation with ADOdb

Comment: I am using Windows7, so I can't install microsoft Jet 4.0. It's not valid for this Windows version!